# Yocto: why is a package included?

Tags: yocto

I am currently using `yocto` for building an embedded linux image for TI AM335x (I am using `hob`, since I find it more comfortable than using command-line).

I start using the recipe for building 'core-image-base' and here is the selection of packages which are included:

[image: initial packages selection]

Now I would like to exclude the package `alsa-utils-1.0.28-r0` from build, since it has some problems compiling for my target and I really do not need it... so, as far as I can understand, I have to remove all the dependencies which brought `alsa-utils` in (that is: `alsa-state` and `packagegroup-base`, looking at following screenshot):

[image: brought in]

So I move to `Package groups` tab and I remove `packagegroup-base` and then I remove `alsa-state` and `alsa-utils` from the `Included recipes`:

[image: removed packages]

Now it seems that `alsa-utils` is there no more... but if I try to build the image, this is the result:

[image: result]

Why? Who is still bringing-in `alsa-utils`? What am I doing wrong? Is there a way (even command-line) to know why a package is brought-in by yocto?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use

```
bitbake -g alsa-utils -u depexp
```

to display a dependency tree you should be able to see who's depending on it.

See [the openembedded wiki](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Inspect_DEPENDS).

Comment: Note that depexp has changed to taskexp in pyro and later.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a proper tool in Yocto to identify why a package is built.

You must first generate the dependency graph for the final recipe you want to build. Then, run `oe-depends-dot --why`:

```bash
 $ bitbake -g core-image-minimal
 $ oe-depends-dot -k busybox -w ./task-depends.dot
Because: core-image-minimal packagegroup-core-boot
core-image-minimal -> packagegroup-core-boot -> busybox
```