# Yocto: How to know why a package is included?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

This is a old question, I know

[Yocto: why is a package included?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238210/yocto-why-is-a-package-included)

[Why is package included in Yocto rootfs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67785619/why-is-package-included-in-yocto-rootfs)

but there is not satisfactory answer.

I get **valgrind** inside my yocto custom image (sustitute valgrind with whatever package name) and I do not why.

Valgrin's recipe **RDEPENDS** variable show what packages will be installed in the image for valgrind runs.

Is there any way to know the reverse function? that is, what recipe has in his RDEPENDS **valgrind**?

**bitbake -g valgrind**  or find **valgrind** in recipes files do not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your answer @aehs29, very instructive, but there are many packages built but not installed.

I undestand `bitbake -g <image-recipe>` tell me **build** dependencies, not **runtime** dependencies and, yes, my custom image has a build dependency from **valgrind** but I am not able to get information about who is the guilty in **task-depends.dot** file.

**valgrind** is not listed in `bitbake -e | grep PACKAGE_INSTALL`, so no luck.

I am using **ipkg** packages, so **log.do_rootfs** file don't show the package dependencies table.

Look into packages files is not feasible because there are many non-installed packages with **valgrind** dependencies.

The strategy has been **first, build the image and then, delete the valgrind recipe, try to build the image again and analize the error**.

```
user@build:~/home/user/yocto-local/build$ bitbake mycustom-image
Loading cache: 100%   |######################| Time: 0:00:01
Loaded 4841 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'valgrind' (but /home/user/yocto-local/sources/meta-imx/meta-bsp/recipes-graphics/imx-gpu-viv/imx-gpu-viv_6.4.3.p2.2-aarch64.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
NOTE: Runtime target 'valgrind' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['valgrind']
NOTE: Runtime target 'opencv' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['opencv', 'virtual/opencl-icd', 'valgrind']
ERROR: Required build target 'mycustom-image' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['mycustom-image', 'opencv', 'virtual/opencl-icd', 'valgrind']

Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

I believe this is not a "formal" practice, but I have not found another.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to get the list of recipes depending on a specific package is to mask it's recipe, generating a bitbake error for reverse dependencies.

`build/conf/local.conf`:

```
BBMASK = "valgrind"
```

Will generate an error, with a clear dependency chain:

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'valgrind' (but *** DEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
ERROR: Required build target 'core-image' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['core-image', '***', 'valgrind']
```

You may need to run this method several times if the recipe is used through several dependency chains.

This answer is similar to Jose Luis Zabalza's but it's a bit quicker to implement rather than finding and deleting all the recipe's `.bb` and `.bbappend`.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a proper tool in Yocto to identify why a package is built.

You must first generate the dependency graph for the final recipe you want to build. Then, run `oe-depends-dot --why`:

```bash
 $ bitbake -g core-image-minimal
 $ oe-depends-dot -k busybox -w ./task-depends.dot
Because: core-image-minimal packagegroup-core-boot
core-image-minimal -> packagegroup-core-boot -> busybox
```

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways to find this out:
`bitbake -g` may be one of them, you are just setting the target incorrectly.
`bitbake -g` gets the **BUILD** dependencies, so, it tells you what package (or task) required valgrind to be built, however doing `bitbake -g valgrind` will tell you what **packages are required for valgrind, not what packages require valgrind (not the same),** you need to do:
`bitbake <your-image> -g`
e.g.
`bitbake core-image-minimal -g`
This will the the build dependencies for your image, and it may tell you what package from your image required valgrind, (open the task-depends.dot file and look for the valgrind lines on the right)

**Bitbake -e may be another way if bitbake -g didnt suffice**

`bitbake -e | grep PACKAGE_INSTALL`

`bitbake -e` will print out bitbake's dictionary, and specifically you should be looking at the `PACKAGE_INSTALL` variable, if valgrind is there, you can see what recipe added it to the variable and hence why its being installed

If valgrind is actually a secondary dependency, that is to say `PACKAGE_A` has an `RDEPENDS+="valgrind"`, and `PACKAGE_A` is required to be installed, then you need to look at the package manager output, this varies depending if you are using RPMs, DEBs or IPKs files, there's more specific ways to find this out but looking at the log.do_rootfs file for your image would probably give you enough information about which package had a runtime dependency to valgrind:

for example if you used RPMs you would see something like this (trimmed for easier reading):

```
$ cat tmp/work/qemuarm64-poky-linux-musl/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs
Package                   Arch       Version                    Repo      Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 base-passwd               cortexa57  3.5.29-r0                  oe-repo  7.2 k
 busybox                   cortexa57  1.35.0-r0                  oe-repo  364 k
 busybox-mdev              cortexa57  1.35.0-r0                  oe-repo  8.7 k
 dropbear                  cortexa57  2020.81-r0                 oe-repo  132 k
 initramfs-live-boot-tiny  qemuarm64  1.0-r12                    oe-repo  8.6 k
 packagegroup-core-boot    qemuarm64  1.0-r17                    oe-repo  5.8 k
 run-postinsts             noarch     1.0-r10                    oe-repo  7.4 k
Installing dependencies:
 base-files                qemuarm64  3.0.14-r89                 oe-repo   13 k
 busybox-inittab           qemuarm64  1.35.0-r0                  oe-repo  7.6 k
 eudev                     cortexa57  3.2.10-r0                  oe-repo  181 k
 libblkid1                 cortexa57  2.37.3-r0                  oe-repo   85 k
 libkmod2                  cortexa57  29-r0                      oe-repo   36 k
 libz1                     cortexa57  1.2.11-r0                  oe-repo   46 k
 musl                      cortexa57  1.2.2+git0+c4d4028dde-r0   oe-repo  364 k
 netbase                   noarch     1:6.3-r0                   oe-repo   14 k
 update-alternatives-opkg  cortexa57  0.5.0-r0                   oe-repo  8.5 k
Installing weak dependencies:
 busybox-syslog            cortexa57  1.35.0-r0                  oe-repo  8.7 k
```

In this example, you can see that I never requested `libz1` to be installed in my image (and others listed as dependencies), however one of the packages from the upper section required those to run.
There's much more information in the `log.do_rootfs` file which may directly tell you what required valgrind, if you still cant find it, go back to bitbake -g  and look for the lines containing the packages above (since those are direct dependencies to your image), one of them should be requiring valgrind.

**The RPM command**

Last but not least, this is tailored for rpms, but the process should be fairly similar for debs or ipks, although the commands will differ, but once you have the list of packages to be installed from `log.do_rootfs` you can query the rpm packages via the rpm command:

I'll use the dropbear package as an example from above:

```
$ rpm -qR tmp/deploy/rpm/cortexa57/dropbear-2020.81-r0.cortexa57.rpm
/bin/sh
libc.so()(64bit)
libz1 >= 1.2.11
libz.so.1()(64bit)
rtld(GNU_HASH)
update-alternatives-opkg
```

So, in my case, the **dropbear** package is the one to blame for the **libz1** dependency.