# Exclude opencv or any unwanted package from building in Yocto completely

Tags: opencv, embedded-linux, yocto

opencv is taking a lot of time to fetch and compile out of all other recipes.
I am doing a headless image and I am sure I don't need opencv at all.
Is there any method?

I tried checking all files inside conf folders (layer.conf) but cannot find anything related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`opencv` is built because an image eplicitly installs it, or it is required as a dependency to an installed package. You must find how it is required and fix this unused dependency. Here's a post that should help you find the recipe that depends on `opencv`: [Yocto: How to know why a package is included?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71121323/yocto-how-to-know-why-a-package-is-included)

Comment: looks like it is daunting task as i could see a LOT of dependencies.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to investigate those dependencies and remove them from the image's install list. However on a minimal headless image you are right that there shouldn't be so many opencv dependencies. I suggest reviewing your `DISTRO_FEATURES` and which image your are using. `core-image-minimal` for instance is the lightest.

Comment: i'm building a custom image designed for a Phytec Segin board spin.

Comment: LAST COMMENT WAS INCOMPLETE --- i'm building a custom image designed for a Phytec Segin board spin. as i'm new to embedded linux i'm not fully aware of yocto build and its underlying concepts. just following the document supplied by the vendor. anyway i will look into DISTRO_FEATURES. thanks for the clarification. maybe opencv is just being used for building the image but not going into the board because when i search for files with pattern "opencv" nothing comes up on board's terminal.